# How to get amplitude of microphone from Android webrtc?

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, data-visualization, audio-streaming

I would like to show visually user mic amplitude if it possible while app in the webrtc video/audio call?
I don't see any helpers methods for this in `AudioSource` or `AudioTrack` any suggestion/ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I need to notify the user if they are on mute and trying to speak.